# create a sql join with more columns

Tags: sql, join, plsql, plsqldeveloper

i want create a sql statemnt (in PL SQL Developer) with a join with comma seperated?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1 JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.tab_id, second_id = t2.tab_id, second_id;
```

I always get a ORA-00920 Exception. If i change it to two Rows:

```
t1.tab_id = t2.tab_id AND t1.second_id = t2.second_id;
```

Then i get rows.

Can some say me if i can use the first step with coma seperated columns?

Greetz

Comment: No you can't use the first step.  Where in the documentation does it say the first step would work???  Have you read the documentation at all???

Comment: Not really, but i think it is possible because oracle have nice easter eggs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a valid condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 t1 JOIN
     TABLE2 t2
     ON t1.tab_id = t2.tab_id AND t1.second_id = t2.second_id;
```

I think Oracle will also let you do:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 t1 JOIN
     TABLE2 t2
     ON (t1.tab_id, t1.second_id) in ( (t2.tab_id, t2.second_id) );
```

Or even:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 t1 JOIN
     TABLE2 t2
     USING (tab_id, second_id);
```

This works because the JOIN keys have the same names in the two tables.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply !!!
But if i have more joins:
SELECT * FROM tab1 t1 JOIN tab2 t2 ON t1.rab_id = t2.tab_id JOIN tab3 t3 ON t2.second_id,t2.third_id = t3.second_id,t3.third_id...

Can i use your solution?

Comment: @Artist_Styler_57 . . . Each `ON`/`USING` clause is its own condition.  Each can take any of these three forms.

Comment: if i use using -> is working ! :)

But if i use ON (t1.tab_id, t1.second_id) = .... -> I get ORA-00920 :(

Comment: @Artist_Styler_57 . . . For some reason, Oracle supports tuples with `IN` but not `=`.  It is a nuance that tend to forget.  I updated the answer.